# Include range [1, 100] on pagesize

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I see that "range" is being used to indicate valid range on most numeric parameters, e.g.

```
32-bit integer, range [0, 2,147,483,647]
32-bit integer, range [1, 2,147,483,647]
```

The smaller valid range for `pagesize` is described in the summary but could also be included in the spec, e.g

```
32-bit signed integer, range [1, 100]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been completed.

Comment: yes, a little bird told me a hour ago. ;-) thanks. This makes generating input validation easier.